# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Tag'

Tags: python, html, xml, beautifulsoup, elementtree

Getting tag error when passing the s output to >> table = ET.XML(s)

```
response = response = requests.get('https://sandbox.jiveon.com/api/core/v3/contents/436669', auth=('dedileep', 'Xento123$'))
data = response.json()
html_doc = data['content']['text']
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html5lib')
s = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'mytable'})
def find_version(ver):
    table = ET.XML(s)
```

Throws error here -----

```
# headers    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final_release.py", line 63, in <module>
    res = find_version(ver)
  File "final_release.py", line 25, in find_version
    table = ET.XML(s)
  File "C:\Users\dedileep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1333, in XML
parser.feed(text)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Tag'


ths = [th.text for th in table.findall('.//th')]
    for tr in table.findall('.//tbody/tr'):
        data = []
        data.append(tr[0].text)
        data.append([x.text for x in tr[1]])
        temp = []
        for x in tr[2]:
            if x.tag == 'a':
                temp.append(x.text)
            else:
                temp.append(x[0].text)
        data.append(temp)
        out = OrderedDict(zip(ths, data))
        print('out:', out)
        if out['Release'] == ver:
            return out
```

The programs Main
    res = find_version(ver)
     if res:
            for key, val in res.items():
                print(key, '-', val)
        else:
            print ('Version not found')

Answer (score 0):

```
s = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'mytable'}) #return a Tag object

ET.XML(s) #require a bytes-like object, like string
```

solution

```
s = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'mytable'}).get_text()
```

It returns all the text in a document or beneath a tag, as a single Unicode string, but i am not sure it's what you want.

Comment: I need to traverse through the tree structure instead of retrieving the text. Editing the original question for that.

Comment: since you use bs4, why you put html back to lxml, that makes no sense,just choice one,and the problem will be mach simple